# Uploading multiple images in frontend - OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, october-form-controller

In the frontend form I have multiple file upload field. So on the form submit, I create a new record in the db and then try to attach multiple images to it, like so:

*Relation for the gallery specified in the model class*

```php
public $attachMany = [
    'gallery' => 'System\Models\File',
];
```

*Frontend form processing*

```php
function onCreate() {
    $data = post();
    
    $newRecord = Record::create($data);
    
    if (Input::hasFile('gallery')) {
        $newRecord->gallery()->create(['data' => Input::file('file_input')]);
    }
}
```

*Frontend form HTML*

```html
<form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8"
      data-request="onCreate" data-request-files data-request-flash>

    <input accept="image/*" name="gallery" type="file" id="gallery" multiple>

</form>
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'disk_name' doesn't have a
> default value

*Setting `$guarded = []` in `vendor/october/rain/src/Database/Attach/File.php` did not help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need `array file field name gallery[]` , to post multiple file and receive them at PHP side.

```php
// html changes 
<input accept="image/*" name="gallery[]" type="file" id="gallery" multiple>
//                      HERE       --^ make it array for multiple files 


// PHP side
// $newRecord = ...your code;
if (Input::hasFile('gallery')) {
    foreach(Input::file('gallery') as $file) {

        $fileModel = new System\Models\File;
        $fileModel->data = $file;
        $fileModel->is_public = true;
        // $fileModel->save(); <- save only if you are adding new file to existing record
        // other wise let differ binding handle this 
       
        $newRecord->gallery()->add($fileModel); 
    }     
}
// $newRecord->save();
```

It should solve your issue.

if any doubts please comment .